# matching row values (text) with column names and return value

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, match

I am trying to find the column name with the same name as the text in another column called "region", and return the corresponding value. My data "df" looks like something similar to this

```
region  A   B   C   D   E   F
H      796  792 844 812 796 776
J      568  564 508 268 320 396
A      820  804 748 528 560 600
X      292  272 260 324 224 200
M      872  812 792 760 668 656
N      100 992  972 880 872 864
C      940  948 952 916 864 880
L      960  956 952 920 900 920
E      980  968 956 940 944 932
F      236  364 460 524 552 616
P      796  792 844 812 796 776
Q      568  564 508 268 320 396
```

And I want to get something that looks like this:

```
region  A   B   C   D   E   F
H       NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
J       NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
A       820 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
X       NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
M       NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
N       NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
C       NA  NA  952 NA  NA  NA
L       NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
E       NA  NA  NA  NA  944 NA
F       NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  616
P       NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
Q       NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

To do this, I tried this piece of code from this other questions ([Loop that matches row to column names and computes an average of the 3 preceding columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48776417/loop-that-matches-row-to-column-names-and-computes-an-average-of-the-3-preceding)) but it only returns the position, and I would like to get the value as shown in the example above.

`apply (df, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x, i){
  position <- (which(x[['region']] == colnames(df)))
})`

How can I modify the code to get the real value?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `dplyr 1.0.0`, you can use `cur_column()`:

```
df %>%
 mutate(across(-region, ~ replace(., cur_column() != region, NA_integer_)))

   region   A  B   C  D   E   F
1       H  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
2       J  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
3       A 820 NA  NA NA  NA  NA
4       X  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
5       M  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
6       N  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
7       C  NA NA 952 NA  NA  NA
8       L  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
9       E  NA NA  NA NA 944  NA
10      F  NA NA  NA NA  NA 616
11      P  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
12      Q  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
```

Arguably not the cleanest `dplyr` way, but you can also try:

```
df %>%
 mutate_at(vars(-1), 
           funs(replace(., .*(deparse(substitute(.)) == region) == 0, NA_integer_)))
```

Or adapting the logic from @markus:

```
df %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 mutate_at(vars(-1), funs(.[match(region, deparse(substitute(.)))]))
```

And one exotic `base R` option:

```
df[-1] <- sweep(t(apply(df[1], 1, rep, length(df)-1)), 2, FUN = `==`, names(df[-1]))*df[-1]
df[-1] <- replace(df[-1], df[-1] == 0, NA_integer_)
```

Answer (score 5):

A fifth option also using `base` functions

```
idx <- na.omit(cbind(match(names(df1), df1$region),
                     1:length(df1)))
vals <- as.integer(df1[idx])
df1[-1] <- NA
df1[idx] <- vals
df1
#   region   A  B   C  D   E   F
#1       H  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
#2       J  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
#3       A 820 NA  NA NA  NA  NA
#4       X  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
#5       M  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
#6       N  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
#7       C  NA NA 952 NA  NA  NA
#8       L  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
#9       E  NA NA  NA NA 944  NA
#10      F  NA NA  NA NA  NA 616
#11      P  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
#12      Q  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
```

**data**

Thanks to @akrun

```
df1 <- structure(list(region = c("H", "J", "A", "X", "M", "N", "C", 
"L", "E", "F", "P", "Q"), A = c(796L, 568L, 820L, 292L, 872L, 
100L, 940L, 960L, 980L, 236L, 796L, 568L), B = c(792L, 564L, 
804L, 272L, 812L, 992L, 948L, 956L, 968L, 364L, 792L, 564L), 
    C = c(844L, 508L, 748L, 260L, 792L, 972L, 952L, 952L, 956L, 
    460L, 844L, 508L), D = c(812L, 268L, 528L, 324L, 760L, 880L, 
    916L, 920L, 940L, 524L, 812L, 268L), E = c(796L, 320L, 560L, 
    224L, 668L, 872L, 864L, 900L, 944L, 552L, 796L, 320L), F = c(776L, 
    396L, 600L, 200L, 656L, 864L, 880L, 920L, 932L, 616L, 776L, 
    396L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: Actually, I was thinking about the `cbind` approach, but later didn't try it

Answer (score 4):

Another base R option:

```
dat[-1][sapply(names(dat[-1]), `!=`, dat$region)] <- NA

dat
   region   A  B   C  D   E   F
1       H  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
2       J  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
3       A 820 NA  NA NA  NA  NA
4       X  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
5       M  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
6       N  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
7       C  NA NA 952 NA  NA  NA
8       L  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
9       E  NA NA  NA NA 944  NA
10      F  NA NA  NA NA  NA 616
11      P  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
12      Q  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one option with `tidyverse` where we reshape into 'long' format with `pivot_longer`, `replace` the elements in 'value' where the 'region' is not equal to 'name' column value and then reshape back to 'wide' format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -region) %>% 
  mutate(value = replace(value, name!= region, NA)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
#   region   A  B   C  D   E   F
#1       H  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
#2       J  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
#3       A 820 NA  NA NA  NA  NA
#4       X  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
#5       M  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
#6       N  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
#7       C  NA NA 952 NA  NA  NA
#8       L  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
#9       E  NA NA  NA NA 944  NA
#10      F  NA NA  NA NA  NA 616
#11      P  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
#12      Q  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
```

---

Another option is `imap`

```
library(purrr)
imap_dfc(df1[-1], ~ replace(.x, .y != df1[['region']], NA)) %>%
   bind_cols(df1['region'], .)
#    region   A  B   C  D   E   F
#1       H  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
#2       J  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
#3       A 820 NA  NA NA  NA  NA
#4       X  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
#5       M  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
#6       N  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
#7       C  NA NA 952 NA  NA  NA
#8       L  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
#9       E  NA NA  NA NA 944  NA
#10      F  NA NA  NA NA  NA 616
#11      P  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
#12      Q  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
```

---

Or using `base R`, we replicate the `names` of the dataset and do a comparison with the 'region' column, change those values in those columns to `NA` based on the comparison

```
df1[-1] <- NA^(df1$region != names(df1)[-1][col(df1[-1])]) * df1[-1]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(region = c("H", "J", "A", "X", "M", "N", "C", 
"L", "E", "F", "P", "Q"), A = c(796L, 568L, 820L, 292L, 872L, 
100L, 940L, 960L, 980L, 236L, 796L, 568L), B = c(792L, 564L, 
804L, 272L, 812L, 992L, 948L, 956L, 968L, 364L, 792L, 564L), 
    C = c(844L, 508L, 748L, 260L, 792L, 972L, 952L, 952L, 956L, 
    460L, 844L, 508L), D = c(812L, 268L, 528L, 324L, 760L, 880L, 
    916L, 920L, 940L, 524L, 812L, 268L), E = c(796L, 320L, 560L, 
    224L, 668L, 872L, 864L, 900L, 944L, 552L, 796L, 320L), F = c(776L, 
    396L, 600L, 200L, 656L, 864L, 880L, 920L, 932L, 616L, 776L, 
    396L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: nice base R solution, liked it!

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option using base R.

```
for (col in names(dat[-1])){
  dat[[col]] <- ifelse(dat$region == col, dat[[col]], NA)
}
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "region  A   B   C   D   E   F
H      796  792 844 812 796 776
J      568  564 508 268 320 396
A      820  804 748 528 560 600
X      292  272 260 324 224 200
M      872  812 792 760 668 656
N      100 992  972 880 872 864
C      940  948 952 916 864 880
L      960  956 952 920 900 920
E      980  968 956 940 944 932
F      236  364 460 524 552 616
P      796  792 844 812 796 776
Q      568  564 508 268 320 396",
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another base R code

```
df[-1]<-Map(function(v,k) {if(is.na(k)) v<-NA else v[-k]<-NA; v},df[-1], 
            match(names(df[-1]),df$region))
```

such that

```
> df
   region   A  B   C  D   E   F
1       H  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
2       J  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
3       A 820 NA  NA NA  NA  NA
4       X  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
5       M  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
6       N  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
7       C  NA NA 952 NA  NA  NA
8       L  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
9       E  NA NA  NA NA 944  NA
10      F  NA NA  NA NA  NA 616
11      P  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
12      Q  NA NA  NA NA  NA  NA
```

Comment: May be bit more compact `df1[-1] <-  lapply(names(df1)[-1], function(x) replace(df1[[x]], x != df1$region, NA))`